# How to optimize query with 10+ joins?

Tags: sql, oracle

My application uses a single query to return all permissions from a user, and this single query has 10 INNER JOINs to create the entire resultset.

Here is a preview of the query (I had to change the table names because of confidential information):

```
SELECT 
    TABLE9.CONTINENT, TABLE9.COD_COUNTRY, TABLE9.DES_COUNTRY, TABLE9.COD_ISO, 
    TABLE7.ID_DEL, TABLE7.COD_DEL, TABLE7.DES_DEL, TABLE7.DES_ZONE, TABLE7.GMT_MINUTES, 
    TABLE7.CANT_MIN_INI, TABLE7.CANT_MIN_SALIDA, TABLE7.CANT_MET_BASE, TABLE5.ID_TS, 
    TABLE5.COD_TS, TABLE2.ID_ROLE, TABLE2.TIMEOUT_SESION, TABLE11.ID_PERMISSION, 
    TABLE3.COD_APLICATION, TABLE3.DES_APLICATION, TABLE6.ID_PLANT, TABLE6.COD_PLANT, 
    TABLE6.DES_PLANT 

FROM TABLE1

INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE2.ID_ROLE = TABLE1.ID_ROLE
INNER JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE3.ID_APLICATION = TABLE2.ID_APLICATION 
 INNER JOIN TABLE4 ON TABLE4.ID_PTS = TABLE1.ID_PTS
INNER JOIN TABLE5 ON TABLE4.ID_TS = TABLE5.ID_TS
INNER JOIN TABLE6 ON TABLE6.ID_PLANT = TABLE4.ID_PLANT
INNER JOIN TABLE7 ON TABLE7.ID_DEL = TABLE6.ID_DEL 
 INNER JOIN TABLE8 ON (TABLE8.ID_USER = TABLE1.ID_USER)
INNER JOIN TABLE9 ON TABLE9.ID_COUNTRY = TABLE7.ID_COUNTRY
INNER JOIN TABLE10 ON TABLE10.ID_ROLE = TABLE2.ID_ROLE
INNER JOIN TABLE11 ON (TABLE11.ID_PERMISSION = TABLE10.ID_PERMISSION 
                              AND TABLE11.ID_APLICATION = TABLE3.ID_APLICATION)

 WHERE TABLE11.COD_PERMISSION <> 'PermissionCode'
   AND TABLE8.ID_USER_AD = 'e5def917-73e6-4b4e-8b5b-436794768c4b'
   AND TABLE8.BOL_ENABLED = 1
```

Here is the execution plan (the cost has decreased after creating some indexes, however it still takes 39 seconds to return 58k rows):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                             | 129 |   118K|    62   (9)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                         |                             | 129 |   118K|    62   (9)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                         |                             | 129 |   118K|    61   (7)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN                           |                             |3461 |  2926K|    61   (7)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | TABLE11                     | 262 | 24890 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |     HASH JOIN                          |                             | 185 |   139K|    57   (8)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | TABLE3                      |  14 |   840 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |      HASH JOIN                         |                             | 185 |   128K|    52   (6)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                | TABLE2                      |  65 |  5785 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |       HASH JOIN                        |                             | 185 |   112K|    48   (7)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL               | TABLE5                      |  56 |  2800 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 11 |        HASH JOIN                       |                             | 185 |   103K|    43   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL              | TABLE9                      |   1 |    70 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |         HASH JOIN                      |                             | 185 | 92870 |    40   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL             | TABLE7                      |  43 |  5375 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 15 |          HASH JOIN                     |                             | 185 | 69745 |    36   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|  16 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL            | TABLE6                      |  43 |  4128 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 17 |           HASH JOIN                    |                             | 185 | 51985 |    33   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|  18 |            NESTED LOOPS                |                             | 193 | 35126 |    20   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE8                      |   1 |    77 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 20 |              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | AK_TABLE8_2                 |   1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  21 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| ADPR_TABLE1                 | 193 | 20265 |    18   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 22 |              INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IX_TABLE1                   | 193 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  23 |            INDEX FAST FULL SCAN        | IX_TABLE4                   |2281 |   220K|    12   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 24 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                   | AK_TABLE10                  |   1 |    73 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What can I do to improve this query?

---

UPDATE

Here are the indexes I have created:

```
create index IX_TABLE11 on TABLE11 (ID_PERMISSION, ID_APLICATION) ONLINE;
create index IX_TABLE8 on TABLE8 (ID_USER, ID_USER_AD, BOL_ACTIVE) ONLINE;
create index IX_TABLE6 on TABLE6 (ID_PLANT, ID_DEL) ONLINE;
create index IX_TABLE4 on TABLE4 (ID_PTS, ID_TS, ID_PLANT) ONLINE;
create index IX_TABLE2 on TABLE2 (ID_ROLE, ID_APLICATION) ONLINE;
```

Comment: Just a note, better post the explain plan as text with proper formatting rather than posting it as an image. A good developer knows how to use SQL*Plus and the formatting commands.

Comment: Jonathan Lewis provides a nice quick (but comprehensive) description of how to obtain a an explain plan as text here, http://allthingsoracle.com/execution-plans-part-1-finding-plans/.

Comment: Replaced the explain plan

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by improving the query?  Do you mean make it run faster, or make the code smaller?  Is this a query that you'll be running very often or only once in a while?

Comment: I need to make way faster. It will be running every time a user signs in, and this happens very often.

Comment: How often does the underlying data change? If it's updated infrequently but read a lot, it might be a candidate for an on-commit fast refresh materialized view.

Comment: Also, how up-to-date are your statistics? Those estimated cardinalities don't look to match anywhere near the 58k rows you say you're getting.

Comment: I don't think the permissions are set very often. I'll try this materialized view. About the statistics, I don't know how to check this on Oracle.

Comment: `select * from user_tab_statistics;` would be a good place to start, especially the `stale_stats` column. You would gather the statistics on a table using `dbms_stats.gather_table_stats`. If you do end up going down the materialized view route, you should still tune the query as much as you can (which includes keeping the statistics up-to-date!).

Comment: The last analyzed data is one week ago and the stale_stats value is 'no' for all tables.

Comment: It seems wrong to return 58K rows to an application.  What does the application do with that much data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the note of the indexes added.  To optimize the query based on your primary criteria of Table8, you want the columns associated with the WHERE clause up front, and ancillary fields AFTER.  Since your criteria is about a specific user via "Table8", I have restructured the query slightly to put that into the primary position and updated the WHERE slightly.

I have also included indexes I would have on the respective tables noting the ones you provided and those that should be slightly adjusted/added.

```
SELECT 
      -- Columns   
   FROM 
      TABLE8 
         INNER JOIN TABLE1
            ON TABLE8.ID_USER = TABLE1.ID_USER
            INNER JOIN TABLE2 
               ON TABLE1.ID_ROLE = TABLE2.ID_ROLE
               INNER JOIN TABLE3 
                  ON TABLE2.ID_APLICATION  = TABLE3.ID_APLICATION
               INNER JOIN TABLE10 
                  ON TABLE2.ID_ROLE = TABLE10.ID_ROLE
                  INNER JOIN TABLE11 
                     ON TABLE10.ID_PERMISSION = TABLE11.ID_PERMISSION 
                     AND TABLE3.ID_APLICATION = TABLE11.ID_APLICATION
                     AND TABLE11.COD_PERMISSION <> 'PermissionCode'
            INNER JOIN TABLE4 
               ON TABLE1.ID_PTS = TABLE4.ID_PTS
               INNER JOIN TABLE5 
                  ON TABLE4.ID_TS = TABLE5.ID_TS
               INNER JOIN TABLE6 
                  ON TABLE4.ID_PLANT = TABLE6.ID_PLANT
                  INNER JOIN TABLE7 
                     ON TABLE6.ID_DEL = TABLE7.ID_DEL
                     INNER JOIN TABLE9 
                        ON TABLE7.ID_COUNTRY = TABLE9.ID_COUNTRY
   WHERE
          TABLE8.BOL_ENABLED = 1
      AND TABLE8.ID_USER_AD = 'e5def917-73e6-4b4e-8b5b-436794768c4b'




Table    Index
TABLE1   (ID_USER, ID_ROLE, ID_PTS)
TABLE2   (ID_ROLE, ID_APPLICATION)   <- index already exists
TABLE3   (ID_APLICATION )
TABLE4   (ID_PTS, ID_TS, ID_PLANT )  <-  index already exists
TABLE5   (ID_TS )
TABLE6   (ID_PLANT, ID_DEL)          <-  index already exists
TABLE7   (ID_DEL, ID_COUNTRY)
TABLE8   (ID_USER_AD, BOL_ENABLED, ID_USER )   <- Added BOL_ENABLED, ID_USER as LAST column index
TABLE10  (ID_ROLE, ID_PERMISSION )
TABLE11  (ID_PERMISSION, ID_APLICATION, COD_PERMISSION )  <-- add COD_PERMISSION
```

From the adjusted indexes, and your comment about it still taking too long, I would offer the following.  It appears your application is browser-based.  If so, your table has specific applications.  What I would SUGGEST doing is the following.  Strip down your query to get DISTINCT applications a person has access to.  They probably have something on the screen that allows them to choose from... Then, once the user picks the SPECIFIC application they want, THEN run the query but also include the criteria for the SINGLE application they select.  So if you have 10 applications, your 58k permissions may now be down to 5-6k records for permissions.

So the first query might be stripped down to the code and description of available applications for the user.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      TABLE3.COD_APLICATION, 
      TABLE3.DES_APLICATION
   FROM 
      TABLE8 
         INNER JOIN TABLE1
            ON TABLE8.ID_USER = TABLE1.ID_USER
            INNER JOIN TABLE2 
               ON TABLE1.ID_ROLE = TABLE2.ID_ROLE
               INNER JOIN TABLE3 
                  ON TABLE2.ID_APLICATION  = TABLE3.ID_APLICATION
   WHERE
          TABLE8.BOL_ENABLED = 1
      AND TABLE8.ID_USER_AD = 'e5def917-73e6-4b4e-8b5b-436794768c4b'
```

Then, once the specific application is selected from the user interface, add that specific application to the main query (notice change just at the join to table2)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      TABLE9.CONTINENT, 
      TABLE9.COD_COUNTRY, 
      TABLE9.DES_COUNTRY, 
      TABLE9.COD_ISO, 
      TABLE7.ID_DEL, 
      TABLE7.COD_DEL, 
      TABLE7.DES_DEL, 
      TABLE7.DES_ZONE, 
      TABLE7.GMT_MINUTES, 
      TABLE7.CANT_MIN_INI, 
      TABLE7.CANT_MIN_SALIDA, 
      TABLE7.CANT_MET_BASE, 
      TABLE5.ID_TS, 
      TABLE5.COD_TS, 
      TABLE2.ID_ROLE, 
      TABLE2.TIMEOUT_SESION, 
      TABLE11.ID_PERMISSION, 
      TABLE3.COD_APLICATION, 
      TABLE3.DES_APLICATION, 
      TABLE6.ID_PLANT, 
      TABLE6.COD_PLANT, 
      TABLE6.DES_PLANT
   FROM 
      TABLE8 
         INNER JOIN TABLE1
            ON TABLE8.ID_USER = TABLE1.ID_USER


            INNER JOIN TABLE2 
               ON TABLE1.ID_ROLE = TABLE2.ID_ROLE
              AND TABLE2.ID_APLICATION = [specific application user selected]


               INNER JOIN TABLE3 
                  ON TABLE2.ID_APLICATION  = TABLE3.ID_APLICATION
               INNER JOIN TABLE10 
                  ON TABLE2.ID_ROLE = TABLE10.ID_ROLE
                  INNER JOIN TABLE11 
                     ON TABLE10.ID_PERMISSION = TABLE11.ID_PERMISSION 
                     AND TABLE3.ID_APLICATION = TABLE11.ID_APLICATION
                     AND TABLE11.COD_PERMISSION <> 'PermissionCode'
            INNER JOIN TABLE4 
               ON TABLE1.ID_PTS = TABLE4.ID_PTS
               INNER JOIN TABLE5 
                  ON TABLE4.ID_TS = TABLE5.ID_TS
               INNER JOIN TABLE6 
                  ON TABLE4.ID_PLANT = TABLE6.ID_PLANT
                  INNER JOIN TABLE7 
                     ON TABLE6.ID_DEL = TABLE7.ID_DEL
                     INNER JOIN TABLE9 
                        ON TABLE7.ID_COUNTRY = TABLE9.ID_COUNTRY
   WHERE
          TABLE8.BOL_ENABLED = 1
      AND TABLE8.ID_USER_AD = 'e5def917-73e6-4b4e-8b5b-436794768c4b'
```

Comment: your query took 26 seconds to run, but still is a long time to way for it.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira, what are the COLUMNS you are querying... maybe something there is causing delay... do you have any SQL statements at the column return level?  Are you getting your 58k records due to a Cartesian result?  Seems like a lot of role info.

Comment: Here are the columns: TABLE9.CONTINENT, TABLE9.COD_COUNTRY, TABLE9.DES_COUNTRY, TABLE9.COD_ISO, TABLE7.ID_DEL, TABLE7.COD_DEL, TABLE7.DES_DEL, TABLE7.DES_ZONE, TABLE7.GMT_MINUTES, TABLE7.CANT_MIN_INI, TABLE7.CANT_MIN_SALIDA, TABLE7.CANT_MET_BASE, TABLE5.ID_TS, TABLE5.COD_TS, TABLE2.ID_ROLE, TABLE2.TIMEOUT_SESION, TABLE11.ID_PERMISSION, TABLE3.COD_APLICATION, TABLE3.DES_APLICATION, TABLE6.ID_PLANT, TABLE6.COD_PLANT, TABLE6.DES_PLANT

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira, it looks like the columns list is truncated, can you edit your original question and paste it there.  Thanks

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira, revised answer as possible solution to be one specific application instead of roles for ALL applications at once.

Comment: Changing the join order will not make any difference except in some extremely rare circumstances.  Oracle automatically chooses the join order based on optimizer statistics.

Comment: @JonHeller,  I understand that, but for a readability, and knowing where things are related down-stream has always been a better way to ensure "what am I asking for" vs just listing all tables in a database just because they are there.  Sometimes I've found others and directed them to remove unecessary tables for this reason.  However, in MySQL and using the STRAIGHT_JOIN clause supercedes the engine's optimizer which in many cases has proven to perform better.

Comment: I convinced the PO (Product Owner) to split this query for each application. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using most of the intermediary tables for joins only and not pulling data from them, create additional indexes in each that index both ids into a single index. That way when the db gathers data to do the join, it looks in the index and then has all the data it needs. All those "TABLE ACCESS FULL" records go away, you'll have only index accesses.

Example indexes:

```
TABLE2 (ID_ROLE, ID_APLICATION)
TABLE4 (ID_PTS, ID_TS)
TABLE6 (ID_PLANT, ID_DEL)
etc...
```

Comment: These indexes already exist. I've updated the question to include the existing indexes.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1. Make sure Oracle is working with all the information available to it - do you have up to date statistics for all tables?
2. Check the columns you're actually returning in the SELECT - Oracle will optimise out some of the joins if the data isn't required.
3. Make sure you have the indexes necessary on the joined columns of each of the joined tables (and make sure the statistics for the indexes are up to date). There are many FULL table scans but at the moment it's hard to say whether Oracle is choosing them as the best option for the table size or whether there are better indexing options.