# Growing data to another table - DB Designing

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

My current project is a social media app somewhat like Facebook. Now the post created by both users and news post (there is a cron running every 15 min and it fetch latest news from various news channels) are keeping in the same table called `post` table. Because of news post the table is growing very fast and the timeline taking more time to load. So we are planing to slit normal post (`post` table) and news post (`news_post` table) to separate tables and then slit old news post to a backup a table (`news_post_backup` table). 

Then on listing post API we have to take union of all these 3 tables and have to sort by post create time and have to take post based on pagination data and other conditions 

I want to know is there any benefit from doing like this. I am doubtful because I have to take union then its again become same table like the previous table structure

MYSQL Version on server is 5.6

**UPDATE**
Here I am adding more information 
 The Query I am running is

```
select CP.id,CP.user_id,post_title,post_content,post_type,new_title,is_spam,spam_reportedby,CP.privacy,CP.link_title,CP.link_content,CP.link_image,CP.is_paid,CP.payment_status,CP.is_breaking,
CUP.id as channel_userspost_id,CUP.parent_id,
SU.full_name as reporteduser_full_name,SU.user_name as reporteduser_user_name,
SU.user_profile_pic as reporteduser_user_profile_pic,
FU.id as from_user_id, FU.full_name as from_user_full_name,
FU.user_name as from_user_name,
FU.user_profile_pic as from_user_profile_pic,
TU.id as to_user_id, TU.full_name as to_user_full_name,
TU.user_name as to_user_name,
TU.user_profile_pic as to_user_profile_pic,
TUA.authentication_status as to_user_authentication_status,
FUA.authentication_status as from_user_authentication_status,
C.verification_status as channel_verification_status,
CUP.created_at,CUP.updated_at,
guid,external_url,
CP.channel_id,CP.rss_channel_id,if(CP.rss_channel_id!=0,RC.rss_name,C.channel_name) as channel_name,
if(CP.rss_channel_id!=0,RC.rss_logo,C.profile_pic) as channel_logo,
C.channel_type,
PCD.like_count as like_count,
PCD.search_count as search_count,
PCD.view_count as view_count,
CM.channel_member_status,C.payment_status as channel_payment_status,C.payment_method as channel_payment_method,
CP.is_live_finished from `channel_users_posts` as `CUP` inner join `channel_posts` as `CP` on `CUP`.`channel_post_id` = `CP`.`id` and `is_spam` = 'N' 
left join `channels` as `C` on `CP`.`channel_id` = `C`.`id` 
left join `rss_channels` as `RC` on `CP`.`rss_channel_id` = `RC`.`id` left join `channel_members` as `CM` on `CM`.`channel_id` = `C`.`id` and `CM`.`user_id` = 427 and `CM`.`channel_member_status` != -1 
left join `test_develop_new`.`users` as `FU` on `FU`.`id` = `CUP`.`shared_from` left join `test_develop_new`.`users` as `SU` on `SU`.`id` = `CP`.`spam_reportedby` 
left join `test_develop_new`.`users` as `TU` on `TU`.`id` = `CUP`.`user_id` left join `common_auth_develop_new`.`user_authentication` as `FUA` on `FUA`.`user_id` = `FU`.`id` 
left join `common_auth_develop_new`.`user_authentication` as `TUA` on `TUA`.`user_id` = `TU`.`id` left join `post_count_details` as `PCD` on `PCD`.`channel_userspost_id` = `CUP`.`id`
where (`CP`.`is_paid` = 'N' or (`CP`.`is_paid` = 'Y' and `CP`.`payment_status` = 'S')) and (`CP`.`channel_id` in (705, 537) or (`CUP`.`user_id` in (8, 12, 427))) and `CUP`.`updated_at` < '2019-04-12 11:09:59.000000' and ((`CP`.`channel_id` != 0 and `CM`.`channel_member_status` is not null) or `CP`.`channel_id` = 0) and ((`CP`.`post_type` != 'BV' or `CP`.`user_id` = 427) or (CP.post_type ='BV' AND EXISTS(SELECT id FROM broadcast_visibility_ids WHERE post_id=CP.id AND post_visibility='PA'))) or (CP.post_type ='BV' AND EXISTS(SELECT id FROM broadcast_visibility_ids WHERE post_id=CP.id AND post_visibility IN ('CNL_A','CRY_A')) AND EXISTS(
SELECT DISTINCT channel_members.channel_id 
FROM channel_members
INNER JOIN channels ON channels.id=channel_members.channel_id
WHERE channel_members.channel_id IN (
705,537
) AND channel_members.channel_id IN (
select channel_id from channel_members where user_id = CP.user_id AND channel_member_status = 1 AND channel_member_role = '1'
) AND channels.channel_type != 46
)) or (CP.post_type ='BV' AND EXISTS(SELECT id FROM broadcast_visibility_ids WHERE post_id=CP.id AND post_visibility IN ('CNL_A','CRY_A')) AND EXISTS(
SELECT DISTINCT channel_members.channel_id 
FROM channel_members
INNER JOIN channels ON channels.id=channel_members.channel_id
WHERE channel_members.channel_id IN (
705,537
) AND channel_members.channel_id IN (
select channel_id from channel_members where user_id = CP.user_id AND channel_member_status = 1 AND channel_member_role = '1'
) AND channels.channel_type = 46
)) or (CP.post_type ='BV' AND EXISTS(SELECT id FROM broadcast_visibility_ids WHERE post_id=CP.id AND post_visibility IN ('CNL_S','CRY_S')) AND EXISTS(
SELECT DISTINCT channel_members.channel_id 
FROM channel_members
INNER JOIN channels ON channels.id=channel_members.channel_id
WHERE channel_members.channel_id IN (
705,537
) AND channel_members.channel_id IN (
select channel_id from channel_members where user_id = CP.user_id AND channel_member_status = 1
) AND channel_members.channel_id IN (SELECT visibility_ids FROM broadcast_visibility_ids WHERE post_id=CP.id AND post_visibility IN ('CNL_S','CRY_S'))
)) order by `CUP`.`updated_at` desc limit 30
```

core post table's name is is `channel_posts` Here is the schema structure for the table

```
CREATE TABLE `channel_posts` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `channel_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `rss_channel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_content` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_type` enum('T','L','I','V','Y','G','A','MI','MV','MY','MG','MA','NS_T','NS_I','C_T','BV') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'T',
  `is_spam` enum('N','Y') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `spam_reportedby` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `privacy` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `guid` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `external_url` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `link_title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `link_content` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_breaking` enum('N','Y') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `is_paid` enum('N','Y') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `payment_status` enum('F','S') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'F',
  `link_image` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_live_finished` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000',
  `updated_at` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

and there is one more table `channel_users_post`

```
CREATE TABLE `channel_users_posts` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `channel_post_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `shared_from` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `new_title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000',
  `updated_at` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

There are 200,000 record in `channel_post` table and 600,000 records in `channel_users_post` table it takes 48586 ms to load.

Comment: use one table with partitioning. so internal the table can be split by date and MySQL create a index for each part see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/partitioning-overview/

Comment: @BerndBuffen Ok thanks I am referring  on it.

Comment: @BerndBuffen The mysql version we are using is 5.6 I think partitioning is supported from 8.0  Is there any other solution or is there any benefit by using the above mentioned methord

Comment: @Salini I have updated my answer

Comment: @Yidna optimized speed from 48586 ms to 17443 ms. Now if i remove order_by updated_at the speed changing to 5548 ms. There exist index for updated_at field. Is there something that I am missing

Comment: Usually this happens if you need a large amount of data from the table still, so it ends up having to sort in the end, which also makes the `LIMIT` less helpful. What is your new query?

Comment: @Yidna Same query added some missing index for joining tables

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered paging your queries rather than splitting the table? Assuming the table is sorted by time, and there's a clustered index on it, you could do something like

```
SELECT id, time, content
FROM post
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 5000
```

to get the 5000th newest post to the 5050th newest post.

In terms of insertion time, you'd probably have a B tree index on the time, so it would be logarithmic.

Additionally, it seems like "content" might be fairly big relative to the rest of the data so you could either make sure the index on time is alt 2, or split that off into its own table and run a separate query when you actually want the content.

---

**EDIT**

That's a very big query and I can tell you almost immediately that the reason why it's so slow has less to do with the size of the table and more to do with the amount of data you're processing (10 `JOIN`s with 11 nested `SELECT`s which have their own `JOIN`s).

Do you have to return all of this at once? Or can you get the very basic information you need and then make some calculations in your application, and then make another query? This way, the disk and memory don't have to do as much work, and you're moving that onto the CPU.

If this query is necessary, please see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585391/how-to-optimize-query-with-10-joins) for how to optimize queries with 10+ `JOIN`s. However, note that in the end, the OP ended up splitting the query since it still takes too long.

The takeaway here is to write smaller queries which usually don't waste as much time/resources.

Comment: Yes there is pagination based on post  update time like  'where updated_at > 000050 limit 30'

Comment: Is that still running slowly? What indexes do you have on your table?

Comment: 5 fields have index user_id, channel_id, rss_channel_id, spam_reportedby, privacy

Comment: Try creating a new index on `updated_at` and see if that speeds things up (this would be a non-clustered index)

Comment: tried but there is no evident change in speed. Actually there is another table called users_post which is used to handle shared posts so when a post is created an entry will be put in this table with post_id, user_id, and from_user_id. (some other fields like title etc) the above mensioned updated_at is from this table. I have set index for that field but there is no change in the speed

Comment: Could you please edit your original question to include: **the entire query that you run that is slow, the table schema, how large the table is, and how long it takes to run**? I want to help you make the query faster but splitting the table will only make it slower and there's not enough information

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to partition the post table by the type of post and date. It is still one table and no code change in the client side. Mysql can do partition elimination for queries.

Comment: partitioning is supported from 8.0 My mysql version is 5.6

Comment: partition is supported in 5.6 or earlier versions. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-overview.html

Comment: optimized speed from 48586 ms to 17443 ms. Now if i remove order_by updated_at the speed changing to 5548 ms. There exist index for updated_at field. Is there something that I am missing